# Store Media Files(Musics and photos) in Database

Tags: database, media, store

İ will do a project that will be like music player. I wanna learn the best way of how can i store musics and photos in Database. I think i'll use paths. What is the best way? If i 2 users want to play same music, does it causes problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring us more details about your requirements. Details like your database, language, etc would be very helpful to answer your question.

Anyway, in general lines saving files in database is a very bad idea, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751/4870465) for more details

Comment: I will use mssql and i'll use asp.net with mvc pattern.